# How to write a method to calculate compound interest by the year?

Tags: java

```
public class Balance {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", balance(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
}
/**
 * @param principal
 * @param rate
 * @param years
 * @return
 */
public static double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) {
    double amount = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the initial investment amount: ");
    principal = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
    rate = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
    years = sc.nextDouble();

    for (int i = 1; i < years; i++) {
        amount = principal * Math.pow(1.0 + rate, years);
        amount += principal;
    }
    return amount - principal;

}
}
```

My problem is with the printf line that I am using within the main method.  Eclipse wants me to change the method balance from void to Object[].  When I do this I must return a value from balance.  So I guess my question is, how would I return the proper value?  Am I on the right track?  Thank you for your time and constructive criticism. :)

EDIT - Thanks for the help everyone,  much appreciated :)  My math is off.  I end up with 1000 more than I should have. hmmm.

So should I just take a 1000 from amount like so:

```
return amount - 1000;
```

Or this:

```
return amount - principal;
```

**EDIT** this is what I am going with since it is due tonight.  Thanks to all for the assistance. :)

Comment: not having touched java for years, but shouldn't:
'return amount;' in the balance method be what you're looking for?
and of course, changing from void to double for the method definition.

edit: on further reflection, what are you trying to do? modify the function so that the output is formatted? Why not modify the 
System.out.println(amount);
line to be printf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points:

- `balance()` cannot be void, because you use its return value in `S.out.printf()`. Do you want balance to print to the screen, or do you want it to yield a number?
- Your loop `for (years = 0; years > 10; years++)` won't run. Think about why. It might help to convert the `for` into a `while`, to visualize why.
- You read in years as a `double`, but then use it as a counter in your loop. What type should it actually be?
- Your `balance()` function takes three parameters, then immediately gets input and obliterates them. Do you want `balance()` to be provided these numbers, or do you want it to fetch them?

Otherwise, you seem to be on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `balance` doesn't return anything, (it's a `void` function). Change it to:

```
public static double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) {
...
```

And inside that function, `return` the balance.

Java is telling you it wants an `Object[]` because `printf` is defined like this:

```
public static void printf(String format, Object ... params) {
    // params is an Object[]
}
```

What this lets you do is pass parameters like this:

```
printf("some string", first, second, etc);
```

It lets you pass as many parameters as you want, and the function can handle them as if you passed an array.

It's exactly the same as if it was defined like this:

```
public static void printf(String format, Object[] params);
```

And you used it like this:

```
printf("some string", new Object[] { first, second, etc});
```

It's just easier to use.

EDIT:

The other option is to not print anything in `main`, but I would definitely advise returning the result and printing it in `main`. This follows the principle of making each function do as little as possible. `balance` should just calculate the balance. Printing it is unrelated.

Comment: printf isn't necessary in main; the balance method prints out the amount.

Comment: @duffymo - Edited. A valid answer, I recommend against it (for reasons outlined above).

Answer (score 3):

Please consider a more drastic re-working of your code; as it is, your `balance()` function is doing *all* the work of your program (and your `printf()` line feels like an afterthought). If you break apart your code based on what the code does, I think you can do much better:

- create a function that prompts the user and then reads in their input
- create a function that calls the previous function three times for principal, rate, and years
- create a function that computes and populates a payment schedule. Keep track of year, balance, payment, principal payment, and interest payment. (Or just the variables you're interested in -- but be aware that programs tend to grow new features, and these variables are often the *second* thing that users (or professors) ask to know when paying down a loan.)
- create a function that prints the selected columns from your payment schedule.
- create a function that orchestrates the previous functions.

When you re-write your program to use a GUI or webservice in three weeks, you'll definitely thank yourself for having written each function to do *one* task, and do it well. You'll also find it far easier to *test* smaller pieces of code that do only one task.

There is the risk of *over engineering* a too-generic solution -- what I'm really trying to suggest is a functional decomposition of your code into multiple smaller routines that do exactly what their name says. You might never move the program into a GUI or webservice or whatever, but you'll definitely be happier when someone reports that your amortization schedule is wrong, that you can control it via simpler programming, rather than having to re-type inputs all day long.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Sounds like a great idea, I just need to get this finished before 11:55pm PST.  Can I do it?

Comment: Are functions and methods synonymous?

Comment: @elevent357, the way I use the terms _functions_ and _methods_, yes. :) They aren't quite the same however: _methods_ are associated with a class (either as a class method or object method) -- and since Java forces everything to be in a class, all functions are methods in Java. _Function_ is normally reserved for [subroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_(computer_science)) that return values. But I'm used to calling them all _functions_ out of habit.

Comment: As for 11:55pm PST, perhaps you should stick with your original course of action -- it's a _good_ start. The separation of duties I suggested is well worth doing when you have some spare time though -- the time saved in testing routines alone is well worth it -- but since the `principal` and `rate` are `double` and the `years` should be `int`, and the schedule is a more complicated multidimensional array of different types, it is probably too much to handle in six hours when so much of it would be new. But please keep a separation of calculation from interface in mind for future projects. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yours is wrong, do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    balance(1000.0, .05, 8.5); 
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this.  It's correct syntax; balance prints out the amount in a loop.  What's the problem?  I wouldn't write it this way, but the answer does address the question.

Comment: They don't know how to do it. Just giving them the answer without even attempting to **explain what's wrong** is not helpful.

Comment: "So I guess my question is, how would I return the proper value?" -  I disagree.  The answer says that an acceptable alternative is to NOT return a value.  That's worth knowing.  Personally, I don't get off on rewriting homework.  I don't think it's helpful to do all the work for someone who's learning.

Comment: Then an acceptable answer would be "You don't need to return the value since it's already being printed: [rest of your answer here]". "Yours is wrong, here's the answer" is not helpful at all.

Comment: I never said your answer was wrong. I said it's not helpful (and apparently I'm not the only one who thinks so). Put an explanation and I'll change my vote. Imagine the question "I tried to calculate 2 + 2 and got 5, what did I do wrong?" and you answer "You're wrong, the answer is 4". Is your answer correct? Obviously. Is it useful? Not at all.